# Adding new nodes or moving segments with Vertex Tool in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, digitizing, vector-layer, qgis-3

I'm used to work with simple polygons and the vertex tool. But now the Vertex Tool doesn't show me the capability of adding new nodes in centerline neither move polygon's segments. The function just disappeared.

[image: Vertex Tool does not show me the '+' anymore, it only moves the existent vertices. (The cursor was on the center of the segment).]

Now the vertex tool only gives me the option to move the existent vertices. There's no more the "+" symbol giving me the option to add it. But, otherwise, it still gives me the option to add a new vertex while at the end of a line:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 3.10+ you can double click on the line to add a new point. You can move the whole line segment, click on it (not at the middle) move the mouse to move the line and click again to move the segment. In my QGIS version I can see the + at the middle of the segment, clicking on it I can add new point. You had better to update to the latest LTR version.

[image]

Comment: I was already at the latest LTR version. Just updated to 3.12 (latest STR version) and the problem persists. Whenever i click at the segment, doesn't matter where in the segment, it selects the nearest node to move it. I tried to change the adherence setting while digitizing but did not worked anyway.

It may be a setting but i don't even know where to start...

Comment: What is your operating system? Can you use double click to add new vertex?

Comment: Windows 10. I couldn't use double-click. I copied the whole user configs folder from the %appdata% folder from other PC where the tool was still working. And worked at all! Add vertex and segment edit function came back. Now i need to find what config controls it.